# Errors in Angular web app and now showing any views

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, angularjs

I'm following a tutorial which is making Angular on Rails. 
here is a JSFiddle URL for the project: https://jsfiddle.net/dcbavw4e/4/

I'm currently getting 2 errors right now:

```
 1. Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token .
Error occuring at :     .controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', 'posts', function($scope, posts) {

2. angular.js:68 Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module flapperNews due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'flapperNews' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.9/$injector/nomod?p0=flapperNews
    at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.9/angular.js:68:12
    at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.9/angular.js:2006:17
    at ensure (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.9/angular.js:1930:38)
    at module (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.9/angular.js:2004:14)
    at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.9/angular.js:4447:22
    at forEach (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.9/angular.js:341:20)
    at loadModules (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.9/angular.js:4431:5)
    at createInjector (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.9/angular.js:4356:11)
    at doBootstrap (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.9/angular.js:1677:20)
    at bootstrap (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.9/angular.js:1698:12)
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.9/$injector/modulerr?p0=flapperNews&p1=Erro….googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.4.9%2Fangular.js%3A1698%3A12)
```

I'm not really sure what I'm doing wrong since I did check App name in `index.html` and `app.js` but they all match.

Comment: the `flapperNews` module isn't available.  It needs to be registered before `MainCtrl` is called.

Comment: I did make a module at the beginning of app.js file "angular.module('flapperNews', ['ui.router'])"

Comment: Your plunker is completely full of bad layout and improperly closing brackets and braces.  Boil it down to the simplest piece of code you can, get it running and work backwards from there.

Comment: @7urkm3n It's all at JSFiddle website

Comment: @DavidL I'm just working on a tutorial from Thinkster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were some syntax errors in your code. At line 24 on the fiddle, you used a ';' it breaks the chain, so controller 'MainCtrl' won't get attached to module 'flapperNews'. (There are a few more mistakes as well.) See the fiddle in comments

```
.factory('posts', [function(){
    var o = {
        posts: []
    };
    return o;
}]);
```

Comment: I thought I needed to put semi colon at the end of whatever I declared? Is it not the case? After I made a change what you've mentioned, I'm having an error at line 48. Can you guess why? is it semi-colon problem again?

Comment: Hm... It's not actually like that. There's something called chaining in JavaScript

Comment: And you haven't closed 'MainCtrl' properly.

Comment: you can either use chaining: angular.module(...).config(...).factory(...)  Or you can go: var myApp = angular.module(...);  myApp.config(...); myApp.factory(..);

Comment: where did I make a mistake on 'MainCtrl'?? I do not see it.

Comment: I have forked your fiddle and made it work. Feel free to work on it https://jsfiddle.net/ess_ess/tL4q0ej1/1/

Comment: About MainCtrl... You wrote it like this : angular.module(..).controller('MainCtrl',['$scope', 'posts', function($scope, posts){....  .controller('PostCtrl', [...])  }]).  You wrapped PostCtrl inside the controller 'MainCtrl'.

Comment: Sweet! Thank you so much!  helps me a lot :)